# Query only direct child and sub-terms of a current term archive

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce on my theme, and it comes with a `product_cat` term as a default category on the shop product. I need to show on every `product_cat` archive its direct child and the sub-tems, but not the sub terms child.

I tried:

```
    <?php $thispage = $wp_query->post; wp_list_categories("taxonomy=product_cat&term=". $term->slug."&title_li=&child_of=".$thispage->slug);?>
```

and it returned all `product_cat` as ul and the sub-term of the archive im in, but not the archive's children.

I tried:

```
global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat');
    foreach ( $terms as $term )
    $currentID = get_the_ID();
    $args=array(
        'taxonomy'=>'product_cat',
        'term' => $term->slug,
        'child_of'=>$currentID
     );

    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>

    <?php if ( $my_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="booklink"><?php the_title();?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and it returned all the the current archive's children and the sub-terms children without the sub-term it self.

So I tried :

```
    $term_id = $terms;
    $taxonomy_name = 'product_cat';
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

and it returned nothing.

Got an idea... if this returns only the sub term:

```
 wp_list_categories( array('child_of' => get_queried_object_id(),'taxonomy' => 'product_cat','title_li' => '','depth' => 1, 'show_option_none'=> ''));
```

maybe i can exacude all of its children in a query args and then call the wp_list_categories. tried:

```
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat'); foreach ( $terms as $term ) $currentID = get_the_ID(); $args=array( 'taxonomy'=>'product_cat', 'term' => $term->slug, 'exclude '=> array('child_of' => get_queried_object_id()) ); $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>
```

but it returns only the sub-term children, not the the proudct_cat children...

Anyone?

I'm Speechless. anyone have a clue?

*sorry for my poor English

Comment: the solution is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29674647/486529

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like

```
    <?php
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
// get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $product->id, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
// separator between links
$separator = ', ';
if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
    $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&child_of=' .get_queried_object_id() . '&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // display post categories
    echo  $terms;
}
?>
```