# Hide subcategories products in the macro-category in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to show products and subcategories of a macro-category but I DON'T want to show the products of the subcategories.

Here's an example of my problem: http://www.idromet.it/jml/wp/categoria-prodotto/prodotti/tubi-raccordi-acciaio-al-carbonio/

"Raccordi in ghisa zincati" is showed 2 times because the first is the category (and its right), the second one i**s the product of that sub-category** (*and I don't want to show it in here*).

Answer (score 7):

The code below should be pasted in the functions.php file located in your child theme folder.

```
function exclude_product_cat_children($wp_query) {
if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
    $wp_query->set('tax_query', array( 
                                    array (
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
                                        'include_children' => false
                                    ) 
                                 )
    );
  }
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');
```

Comment: this code definitely works, but for the products to be hidden it is necessary to set only the child category, not all the tree.

Comment: This code works almost well, except now I have only 6 products on first page instead of 20. Excluded subcategory products are somehow still counted in.